# SQL Server: stored procedure and CLR Proc return data differently

Tags: sql-server-2008, delphi, delphi-xe2, sqlclr

I'm using Delphi XE2 to call a stored procedure that returns data. The stored procedure is basically:

```
set nocount on -- ensures that Delphi will see that dataset
...
exec StoredProcThatReturnsData
...
update [table]
update [another table]
```

When the main procedure is a T-SQL procedure, it finishes executing the main procedure including the last `update` statements **before it returns the data** to Delphi.

When the main procedure is a CLR procedure, it returns the data at the moment the sub-procedure finishes executing and doesn't run the `update` statements until I close the `TSQLQuery` object in Delphi.

The Delphi code looks like this:

```
rpt := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
try
  rpt.MaxBlobSize := -1;
  rpt.SQLConnection := ASqlConnection;
  rpt.SQL.Text := 'exec RunMainProc';
  rpt.Open;
  // do some things that depend on the update statements
  // process the 'rpt' data
finally
  FreeAndNil(rpt);
end;
```

The CLR proc looks like this:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlProcedure]
public static void RunReport(SqlGuid ReportID, SqlGuid UserID, SqlBoolean ForDownload)
{
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
  {
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
      cmd.Connection = con;
      cmd.CommandText = "[identical SQL as T-SQL proc]";
      SqlContext.Pipe.ExecuteAndSend(cmd);
    }
  }
}
```

Why does the T-SQL procedure finish executing before returning the data while the CLR procedure waits to run the `update` statements until after Delphi closes/destroys the `rpt` query?

Comment: What happens in .NET when you do a `exec RunMainProc` there?

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers: Thanks for pointing me in that direction.  It helped me discover the issue.

Comment: You are welcome (: Every time when I loose things or break things I ask myself what did I do last...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jeroen, I tried running things from somewhere besides Delphi and found the issue.

When I was converting the T-SQL procedures to CLR, I added some debug code to the sub-procedure, which made it return **two** datasets instead of **one**.  It was the second *pending* dataset that caused the CLR version of the procedure to hand back the data before the main procedure finished executing.

Once I removed the debug code (so only **one** dataset was generated), the T-SQL and CLR versions of the procedure ran exactly the same -- the main procedure finished running before the data was handed back to Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

Does your SP return records or not ? It seems ti does not. Then you should not call Open on Query.
Open prepares DataSet to fetch data rows, and since requests can go long - it fetches them on demand. When you call *TDataSet.Next* and *TDataSet.Last* and such.
So i think, if you want to sync with SP after .Open you can call *rpt.Last*.

But correct way would be not use *Open* at all and use *ExecSQL* instead.

http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SqlExpr_TSQLQuery_ExecSQL.html

PS: in C# you call *SqlContext.Pipe.Execute*, not *Open*. And same expected to apply to Delphi, which in some sense was model for .Net and OLE DB

Comment: The main stored procedure returns the data that is pulled from the sub-procedure.  So I do need to use `Open` in Delphi.  Will try the `rpt.Last` though.